# JQuery Ajax form serialize does not gives new result when submit first time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a trouble while submitting data with *jquery ajax call*

the following **jquery ajax call function I am using**

```
$(".update-pages").bind('submit',function(){
        var urlReq = "perform/update_pages.php?sbmt_change=&" +$(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
          method : 'GET',
          url : urlReq,
          success : function(data){
              alert(data);
          }
       });
       return false;
    });
```

The HTML form is:

```
<form action="perform/update_pages.php" class="update-pages" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" value="about" id="getLoc" name="about" />
    <textarea name="txt" rows="20">

    </textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="UPDATE" name="sbmt_change" />

</form>
```

PHP file is (*perform/update_pages.php*):

```
if (isset($_GET['sbmt_change'])) {
        $contents = urlencode($_GET['txt']);
        $data = file_get_contents("http://localhost/web/about.php?contents=$contents");
        $put = file_put_contents("../../../mysite/about.php", $data);
        if ($put) {
            echo 'updated'; 
            exit();
        }else{
            echo 'unable to update pages';
            exit();
        }
}else{ // if not form submitted
    header("location:../");
    exit();
}
```

**Problem**: When I submit data, `serialize()` send old result that was before change in `textarea`, but when I submit again `serialize()` sends new result, and the same trouble starts again and again. the **even time submit** send the new data but **odd time submit** sends old data.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you declaring `urlReq` twice?

Comment: Can you also show us the PHP code that is processing this data

Comment: What is the version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: Looks like he has dumped the question and gone to lunch. **How annoying**

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes please my edited question for PHP code

Comment: @tovishalck jQuery v2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

**This is your code I just tested in my system and it is working fine. I am getting proper data at each submission.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".update-pages").bind('submit',function(){
        var urlReq = "server.php?sbmt_change=&" +$(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
          method : 'GET',
          url : urlReq,
          success : function(data){
              alert(data);
          }
       });
       return false;
    });
})

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="server.php" class="update-pages" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" value="about" id="getLoc" name="about" />
    <textarea name="txt" rows="20">

    </textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="UPDATE" name="sbmt_change" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**server side code :**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['sbmt_change'])) {
        print_r($_GET);
}else{ // if not form submitted

}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. but it gives me problems while odd time submission.

Answer (score -1):

Hi below is some changes in you code please use the modified code below

```
<form action="" class="update-pages" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" value="about" id="getLoc" name="about" />
    <textarea name="txt" rows="20">

    </textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="UPDATE" name="sbmt_change" />
```

```
<script>
    $(".update-pages").bind('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST', //also use GET
            url: 'http://localhost:82/stack/get.php', //HERE IS FULL SITE URL OF YOUR FILE
            data: $('.update-pages').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Comment: The OP is obviously a beginner. Suggesting they amend there code to use a `localhost` site on port 82 when their code made no reference to a domain or a port number **is just misleading** ___Dont just dump a piece of code you have lying around as an answer!___

Comment: thanks for your help but this return the data of another HTML page and does not solved my problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly what is wrong with this code? It is working fine on my system. I have tested it before answering  So you better post the other answer rather than giving opinion and rating about other ones.